# Disable Next/Prev Keys in Google Keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

When using Google keyboard in my EditText, the tap and hold on Enter key shows emojis and next/prev keys. On pressing next/prev keys, the EditText loses focus. Is there any way to not show next/prev while I need emojis in my app.

[image]

Comment: try to use imeOptions

Comment: @NiravRanpara I'm already using android:imeOptions="actionDone", and it's not fulfilling my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, just set the XML attributes android:imeOptions="actionDone".

Comment: Already using android:imeOptions="actionDone", and it's not fulfilling my requirement.